# Xamarin ImageZoom Converting from Java to C#

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, animator

I've been trying to resolve this for a few days to no avail. I'm trying to create an ImageZoom function for Xamarin.Android, then I will move to making one for Xamarin.iOS.

What I'm doing is the Android example code found here: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

I'll include the relevant code here too:

```
Class ImageZoom
{
    int mShortAnimationDuration;
    private Animator mCurrentAnimator;

    private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {
    // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it
    // immediately and proceed with this one.
    mShortAnimationDuration = Android.Resource.Integer.ConfigShortAnimTime;

    if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
        mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
    }

    // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
    final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(
            R.id.expanded_image);
    expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);

    // Calculate the starting and ending bounds for the zoomed-in image.
    // This step involves lots of math. Yay, math.
    final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
    final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
    final Point globalOffset = new Point();

    // The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail,
    // and the final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the container
    // view. Also set the container view's offset as the origin for the
    // bounds, since that's the origin for the positioning animation
    // properties (X, Y).
    thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
    findViewById(R.id.container)
            .getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
    startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
    finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

    // Adjust the start bounds to be the same aspect ratio as the final
    // bounds using the "center crop" technique. This prevents undesirable
    // stretching during the animation. Also calculate the start scaling
    // factor (the end scaling factor is always 1.0).
    float startScale;
    if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height()
            > (float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height()) {
        // Extend start bounds horizontally
        startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
        float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
        float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
        startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
        startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
    } else {
        // Extend start bounds vertically
        startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
        float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
        float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
        startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
        startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
    }

    // Hide the thumbnail and show the zoomed-in view. When the animation
    // begins, it will position the zoomed-in view in the place of the
    // thumbnail.
    thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Set the pivot point for SCALE_X and SCALE_Y transformations
    // to the top-left corner of the zoomed-in view (the default
    // is the center of the view).
    expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
    expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

    // Construct and run the parallel animation of the four translation and
    // scale properties (X, Y, SCALE_X, and SCALE_Y).
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set
            .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
                    startBounds.left, finalBounds.left))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
                    startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X,
            startScale, 1f)).with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                    View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f));
    set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
    set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }
    });
    set.start();
    mCurrentAnimator = set;

    // Upon clicking the zoomed-in image, it should zoom back down
    // to the original bounds and show the thumbnail instead of
    // the expanded image.
    final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
    expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
            }

            // Animate the four positioning/sizing properties in parallel,
            // back to their original values.
            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            set.play(ObjectAnimator
                        .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator
                                .ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                                        View.Y,startBounds.top))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator
                                .ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                                        View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator
                                .ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                                        View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
            set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
            set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }
            });
            set.start();
            mCurrentAnimator = set;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Changing the capitalisation in letters and words is fine, and handling the Rect(). The main problem I have is implementing the two Java Animator Listeners in C#:

```
set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }
});
```

&

```
set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCurrentAnimator = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCurrentAnimator = null;
    }


 });
```

The above gives the following error:

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface
>   'AnimatorListener'

I understand why I get the above error but I'm not sure how to actually implement the two AnimatorListenerAdapters with just some of the methods overridden in C# to the same affect as Java. Answers with code examples are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Create separate subclasses of `AnimatorListenerAdapter` each with the method overrides as shown in the Java sample, then instead of instancing and setting `AnimatorListenerAdapter` use your subclassed version.

Comment: @SushiHangover Would you be able to provide an example please, I had tried something like that but was still unsure. As in, how to achieve the same functionality in the listeners that are in separate files/classes (assuming?) as they do in the Java sample.

Answer (score 0):

Just create you own ListenerAdapter and subclass it like so:

```
public class MyAnimatorListenerAdapter : AnimatorListenerAdapter
{
    public override void OnAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
    {
        base.OnAnimationEnd(animation);
        //Do stuff
    }

    public override void OnAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
    {
        base.OnAnimationCancel(animation);
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Then just set your Listener to an instance of your new adapter